# How to set a global variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to increment a counter each time I call a function.
But it is being set to 0 each time I call it.
How can I maintain the updated value of nextKeyIndex?

I am calling getKey function from a javascript file.
Other javascript file which should return updated index (from 0 to 4) has below code..

```
var nextKeyIndex=0;

function getKey() {
   if (nextKeyIndex == 4)
      nextKeyIndex = 0;
   else
      nextKeyIndex = nextKeyIndex + 1;

   alert(nextKeyIndex);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a global variable in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581679/how-do-i-set-a-global-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: You're calling getKey() in a different file?

Comment: Yes, I am calling it from a different file.

Comment: Can you post the code of this another file also?

Comment: Its working even though call is from other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables in javascript are by default global if you do not explicitly declare them within a function. Are you sure that the first line declaration (var nextKeyIndex=0) is not being re-run or reloaded somewhere?

```
<a href="#" onclick="getKey()">Click Me To Increment</a>

var nextKeyIndex=0;

getKey=function() {
   if (nextKeyIndex == 4)
      nextKeyIndex = 0;
   else
      nextKeyIndex = nextKeyIndex + 1;

   alert(nextKeyIndex);
}
```

It works for me in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJYx2/

Answer (score 1):

I tried you code as below and its working for me. Please try below code.

```
<script>
var nextKeyIndex=0;

function getKey() {
   if (nextKeyIndex == 4)
      nextKeyIndex = 0;
   else
      nextKeyIndex = nextKeyIndex + 1;

   alert(nextKeyIndex);
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="getKey()" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to set a global variable in javascript?

You can set a global variable if you declare something without `var` or declare it as part of `window` object

```
global = 10; // global variable
window.global = 10; // also global variable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nextKeyIndex=0;

function getKey() {
   if (nextKeyIndex == 4){
      nextKeyIndex = 0;
   }else{
      nextKeyIndex = nextKeyIndex + 1;
}
   alert(nextKeyIndex);
}
```

Comment: No, brackets are not the problem.